# android what is binary search or btree collection

Tags: android, search

What is the collection class that implements binary search or B tree.

I am currently using `List<Item>    allItemList`  finding any element is very slow as i have to start from start to end and compare each item.

I wanted to know if any class is there which will do this?

Comment: see Arrays.binarySearch

Comment: I needed answer for this question

Answer (score 1):

If your allItemList is ArrayList then your can sort it and then user Collections.binarySearch to find elements using binary search.

You can also use TreeSet, from docs you can read:

`This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains).`

but it does not implement List interface

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.binarySearch(myList, searchingItem, comparator)
```

but before you call it you have to sort your list with:

```
Collections.sort(myList, comparator);
```

Comment: sorting is again costly.... B-tree would be better or something which maintains list sorted

Comment: @Vijay it is questionable statement. Adding to list is cheaper. So if you add a lot and then only query then it might be better for you.